# What is the difference between .so.3.0 and .so in opencv?

Tags: linux, opencv, shared-libraries, opencv3.0

After installing opencv 3 on my linux system I noticed that for every .so file there was a corresponding .so.3.0 file. Is the extra extension just to differentiate between two different files, or is the .so.3.0 actually a different kind of shared library? I haven't seen this convention used anywhere else so I thought it was a little odd.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/a/402595

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I summarized the answer below for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A detailed explanation is provided here https://serverfault.com/questions/401762/solaris-what-is-the-difference-between-so-and-so-1-files/402595#402595

Essentially, the .so file is a symbolic link to the .so.3.0, which is the actual shared library file. The .so specifies which version of the library file should be used.